# Application frozen by a QMessageBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have this small piece of code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <QMessageBox>

class MyWidget:public QWidget{
public:
    QBasicTimer timer;
protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent*e){
        if(e->timerId()==timer.timerId()){
            timer.stop();
            QMessageBox::critical(this,"Oups",
                                 "I hope you were not resizing the main window.");
            return;
        }
        QWidget::timerEvent(e);
    }
};

int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    MyWidget w;
    w.timer.start(2000,&w);
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I display a `QWidget` which displays a `QMessageBox` after two seconds.
If **I am resizing my main window when the popup is displayed**, my mouse cursor does not come back to normal (it keeps a "resizing a Window" look) and **the interface is completely frozen**. I cannot close the popup and I cannot move my mouse over the Taskbar.

The only solution is to navigate with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to Visual studio and stop the debugger.

System (if it matters):

- Windows 7 64 bit.
- Visual Studio 2013 + Addin
- Qt 5.3.0 alpha

**My questions:**

- Is it a known bug?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a simple workaround?

Comment: I think your question might be related to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383464/qmessagebox-blocks-qdialog)

Comment: @maddin45 I do not think it is. I know that I have a modal Dialog Box. My problem is that I cannot even click on the message box itself.

Comment: Snippet is not working at all...

Comment: @Samoth Sorry. I posted a corrected version. I tested it in Qt Creator and Visual Studio.

Comment: It seems to be a bug introduced in Qt5. I tested and can confirm the same behaviour in 5.2.0 but not in 4.8.4

Comment: I can't reproduce the freeze, using mac OS and Qt5.2.1, sorry.

Comment: May be it doesn't work, when tries to process window event while processing another window event? \Try to use QTimer with the signal instead of QBasicTimer and event.

Comment: @Lol4t0 it doesn't change anything to use a QTimer, I just tried and got the same behaviour.

Comment: It could be an old bug that came back from the dead with Qt5: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-15451
Weirdly it doesn't block on Qt 4.8.4 though...

Comment: For everything which is bug related in qt, you should post to their qt-interest mailing list

Comment: I tested QT 4.7 in windows, behavior is not correct either. The window will snap back to its original size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Digia Support, this is a bug. However, they provide an acceptable workaround.

Just before the `QMessageBox::critical` we can add a `ReleaseCapture();` like this:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    ReleaseCapture();
#endif
```

The behavior goes back to Qt 4.7 though (cf comment from user3183610). The window will snap back to its original size.

Comment: Can you please attach a link of the bug?

Comment: @michalis Qt has changed its bug reporting tool. If the [link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-15451) I provided years ago does not work anymore, I am afraid you are out of luck.